# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Groupdeals_Helper_Data' not found in magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, php-5.4, extensions

I installed **groupdeals** extension and now when I uninstalled it. Its giving frontend error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Groupdeals_Helper_Data' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

Backend is working fine for me..

I cleared cache, session files and done lots of changes told in stackoverflow question answers like

1) **[magento-fatal-error-class-mage-foomancommon-helper-data-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873064/magento-fatal-error-class-mage-foomancommon-helper-data-not-found)**

2) **[magento-php-fatal-error-class-xxxxxx-not-found-in-mage-php-on-line-516](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732932/magento-php-fatal-error-class-xxxxxx-not-found-in-mage-php-on-line-516)**

3) **[magento-1-7-fatal-error-class-mage-profile-helper-data-not-found-in-mage-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661237/magento-1-7-fatal-error-class-mage-profile-helper-data-not-found-in-mage-php?rq=1)**

and so on.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "uninstalled" it? Haven't you forgotten a file somewhere, such as an XML in `/etc/modules/` ?

Comment: You can try a little trick sometimes it works , as do disable / enable magento compiler and check if it works .

Comment: @JulienLachal I already deleted all files I could see with name "groupdeals"

Comment: @webkul "disable / enable magento compiler " not works always....:)

Answer (score 3):

We need more details about the extension. Without that, we cannot point to a specific reason of this error.

However, this error most probably occurs to due to in-proper uninstallation of **groupdeal** extension. So make sure you have removed every bit of files of that extension.

The possible locations where you can find files related to this extension is :

> 1) app\etc\modules\{Namespace_Module.xml}
>
> 2) app\code\{community|local}\{Namespace}
>
> 3)
>   app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\{layout_update_file_of_extension.xml}
>
> 4)
>   app\design\frontend\base\default\template\{directories_specific_to_this_extension}
>
> 5) app\design\adminhtml\{base |
>   default}\default\layout\{layout_update_file_of_extension.xml}
>
> 6) app\design\adminhtml\{base
>   |default}\template\{directories_specific_to_this_extension}
>
> 7) skin\{frontend | adminhtml}\{base | default
>   }\default\{any_skin_files_related_to_extension}

Comment: actually It was not my project. someone installed this on client's server.
But now client want me to uninstall it.
well point 5, 6, 7 helped me bit.. because I didn't deleted these files.
and now I deleted them. but again same fatal error.
see if you can help me more.
and Thanks for your answer.

Comment: lol....
magento developers closed my question as off-topic..its called little knowledge is very dangerous....lol

Comment: just set
1. manage .htaccess file for localhost
2. set/modify database values like Table: admin_user and Table: core_config_data
3. clear cache
4. in admin panel -> groupdeals extension : i did'nt disabled groupdeals extension rather just done changes in 2 setting of it..
Enable Subscribe Popup - No (from 'Yes')
Enable Give as a Gift - No (from 'Yes')
nothing else
and no popup on page load
frontend & backend running good
on product click .....product detail page also working fine
no side effect...

Comment: well,
this showed me, you guys didn't used this type of extension....
 no problem
go ahead....
and Thanks for answer and closing my question......

Comment: @faraz whatever extension you have used, no one can help u further on this, because the given details are not suffient to help you out. the error in the question can happen from anywhere.

Comment: but now I got solution myself.....i wrote above what I did for making it working...
well chill out man...:)